# Matrix Equation solver Python

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, equation

Here's the problem: I am trying to solve a second order matricial equation of the form :
[image]

Where X(to find) and C (known) are of sizes [nxn]. (n is on the order of 1000).
C is a symmetric covariance matrix known. (and X should be symmetric too)

Here is my code:

```
from sympy import solve
from sympy import Indexed, IndexedBase, Tuple
import numpy as np

X = IndexedBase('X',shape=(n,n))
eqs = Tuple(np.dot(X,X)-np.dot(C,X)-np.eye(n))
solve(eqs, X)
```

Is it the right way to do it? My code is taking ages.
I am looking for any type of algorithm that could help me solve this kind of equation efficiently.

Comment: What is  `np` in your code? NumPy? Are you interested in a numerical solution or an analytical solution? Currently you seem to be mixing up the two.

Comment: Yes sorry I edited, np is numpy. I am interested in an analytical solution if possible.

Comment: Is it possible to provide what `q`, `L` and `C` are? You need not give the full 1000x1000 version of C. Just 3x3 will also be enough and you can later generalize for your 1000x1000 case.

Comment: q*L are just to give the size. No deep meaning, and C is just a covariance matrix of an input but here it's not really the problem. I am looking for a general way to solve this type of equation (with known C) with python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the symbolic work can be done by hand:

```
X^2 - CX - I = 0
-> X^2 + 2EX - I = 0          // sub C = -2E
-> X^2 + 2EX + E^2 - I = E^2  //add E^2 to both sides (i.e., complete the square)
-> (X + E)^2 = E^2 + I        //simplify and add I to both sides
-> X+E = +/-(E^2 + I)^(1/2)   //take square root (now we may have more than one answer)
-> X = -E +/- (E^2 + I)^(1/2) //subtract E from both sides
```

Matrix square-root may or may not be something you want to solve symbolically.  SymPy will certainly let you represent it symbolically, but it has proven unable to compute it numerically, thus far in my attempts (in Python3 on MinGW64).

Your matrix C is symmetric, so we can check whether the term under the square-root (i.e., power of `1/2`) has an explicit computation formula.  A few preliminary facts:

Per [Wikipedia (Symmetric Matrix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix):

1. The sum and difference of two symmetric matrices is again symmetric.
2. given symmetric matrices A and B, then AB is symmetric if and only if A and B commute.
3. every real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable by a real orthogonal similarity.

Per [Wikipedia (Square Root Of A Matrix)::Explicit Formulas::ByDiagonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#By_diagonalization)

4. for any diagonalizable matrix `A=VDV^(-1)`, then `A^(1/2) = VD^(1/2)V^(-1)`.

Working up from `C` we ask, is `E^2+I` diagonalizable (so as to have an easy explicit formula for matrix square-root)?
`C` is symmetric, and `E = -(1/2)C`; the scalar multiply doesn't change the symmetry of `C` since it affects every cell; hence `E` is symmetric.
`E^2 = (E * E)` commutes, so `E^2` is symmetric.
Finally, `I` is symmetric, so `(E^2 + I)` is symmetric.

Thus the square-root via diagonalization of (4) above could be used.  And the square-root of a diagonal matrix is computed by taking the square-root of the elements on the diagonal.  Here you may run into another issue, that if these elements are negative, your answer will be complex.  There are also potentially multiple answers for each square-root, potentially giving you a few answers to consider.  This is most likely why SymPy fails to give a numerical answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't right. NumPy is for numerical computation, it is not going to create a SymPy object representing the left hand side of your equation. And it's not going to help you obtain an analytic solution.  Here is an example of solving a matricial system with SymPy; it is 2 by 2 rather than 1000 by 1000.

```
import sympy as sym
X = sym.Matrix(sym.MatrixSymbol('X', 2, 2))
covar = sym.Matrix([[2, 1], [1, 3]])
sym.solve([X**2 - covar*X - sym.eye(2), X-X.T], X)
```

Notice that multiplication of SymPy matrices is just `*`. The first equation is what you wrote, the second requires X to be symmetric (`X.T` is the transpose of X).

However, already 3 by 3 case is problematic, and 1000 by 1000 is utterly hopeless. One doesn't simply solve a system of 500,000 nonlinear equations by throwing it at SymPy.

You could try SciPy's multivariable solvers to obtain some numerical solutions, but it's going to be just that, one numerical solutions of many.  The right approach to matricial equations like `X**2 - C*X - I = 0` is not to throw them at a computer; it is to do math.

Comment: okay thank you, I wasn't familiar with sympy (and didnt find any good doc yet). However even If i "do the math" I may be able to simplify my equations' system but I will still need my computer to do it (~500,000 equations are too much ;p). I thought SciPy could do it. **If not any suggestions on approximation technics?**

Comment: Could you provide a start with SciPy's multivariable solvers?

Comment: My suggestion is to step back from the "I need to solve this equation" and review the larger picture. Suppose SymPy handed you a solution, With 500,000 equations, you would have a solution as 500,000 complicated formulas, which together would fill out not a book but a small library. What would you do with that library, read it?  Or, if SciPy gives you 500,000 numbers, are you going to read them one by one?   (And yes,  can provide a start with multivariable solvers, but I choose not to).

Comment: Maybe I wasn't very clear. I will use those "500,000 numbers", aka the solution to this equation or at least an approximated one, for further computation, so no I am not gonna read them but my computer will.